# Can I carry used computer parts from India to Germany

Tags: indian-citizens, germany, berlin

I have a desktop PC. I am moving to Berlin in a few months.

Can I dismantle to desktop (excluding monitor), and carry the inidividual parts in my check in baggage. Is there any restriction in carrying such items?

Comment: You can carry what you like, but you might be liable for import duty and VAT depending on the value of the items as assessed by German customs, and whether any exemptions are available for your specific circumstances. If in doubt, use the red channel and declare everything.

Comment: Why bother with disassembling it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton A PCIe slot or the mounting for most air coolers isn't made for the rough handling in transport. By disassembling it, the risk of damage is smaller but I would personally just take the whole PC, stuff the inside full with clothes and hope for the best. Additionally, everybody recognizes a complete PC but many may not recognize individual components which may raise suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

Computer parts should be no problem, especially used ones. There is only a restriction on the value of the items that you are trying to import. If you are not sure, you can always use the red exit. The staff there will be happy to help you. You can find additional information here:
[Entering Germany - Zoll.de](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/entering_germany_node.html)

I wish you a pleasant stay.